# I was trying to make an app that automatically detects the OTP send via the default Android messaging app

Tags: android, android-intent, one-time-password

Here is my code:

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        final String sentOTP = RandomNum();
        if (!etNumber.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + etNumber.getText().toString().trim());
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sentOTP);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
        inish();
        Intent i = new Intent(sendActivity.this, CheckerActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("generatedOTP", sentOTP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(sendActivity.this, "Enter the phone NUMBER!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   }
});
```

Upon clicking the button, the messaging app opens and is backgrounded by the CheckerActivity that is started. What I want is that when the message app opens, I send the message, and as soon as I click the Send button to send the message, CheckerActivity also gets started.

How can I accomplish this? Do I need to set some additional Intent flags?

Comment: Make receiver which is called when message is send and from this broadcast receiver check that last sent message is yours. And then call your CheckerActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Start SMS intent with results, on results you can then start your activity.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == SMS_REQUEST) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent i = new Intent(sendActivity.this, CheckerActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("generatedOTP", sentOTP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        }
    }
will this work  ??

Comment: yes, that should do the trick, dont forget to start your sms activity like..'startActivityForResult(smsIntent, SMS_REQUEST);'